# Git Merge Adds New File Instead of Conflict Markers - CONFLICT (rename/add)

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

When running `git merge origin master` on the command-line I'm not getting the usual conflict markers `<<<<<<` but instead conflicting files are being copied down to my local environment.

Could this have something to do with the folder-name being changed?

Example:

```
git fetch origin master && git merge origin master
CONFLICT (rename/add): Rename javascript/main.js->js/main.js in HEAD. js/main.js added in %commit-hash%
Adding as js/main.js~%commit-hash% instead
```

Then I have 2x files on my local: `js/main.js` & `js/main.js~%commit-hash%`

How can I make git give me conflict markers to work with instead of a new file?

& Can anyone shed some light on why this happens?

- *note: `%commit-hash%` is just a placeholder for the actual commit-hash for sake of example.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Try using `-X find-renames=<value>` to get different rename detection.  Or, if that won't work or you don't like that method, extract all the files from the multiple stages stored in the index if necessary, and then use `git merge-file` to create the conflicts "by hand".

#### Long

This is a *high level* conflict: a conflict that occurs due to *multiple different files* with changing names, instead of a conflict that occurs within *one single file*.

Git has told you exactly what the problem is:

> Rename `javascript/main.js->js/main.js` in `HEAD` ...

So when comparing the current or `HEAD` commit to the common merge-base from which both you and they started, Git finds that *you* took `javascript/main.js` and renamed that file to `js/main.js`.

> ... `js/main.js` added in *`hash`*

They, whoever they are, left file `javascript/main.js` in `javascript/main.js`, but then created a *new* file called `js/main.js`.

Because there can only be *one* file named `js/main.js`, Git has to do something special.  It can't put *your* `js/main.js` (that you renamed from `javascript/main.js`) into `js/main.js` *and* put *their* newly-created but different `js/main.js` into `js/main.js`.  So it has put their `js/main.js` into `js/main.js~hash`.

> How can I make git give me conflict markers to work with instead of a new file?

Maybe you can do this trivially, and maybe not.

First, you have to decide whether Git's analysis of the situation is correct.  *Did* you rename `javascript/main.js` to `js/main.js`?  And, what *did* they do: *did* they keep their original `javascript/main.js` and add a new and different `js/main.js`, or did they actually rename their `javascript/main.js` and it's just that Git didn't realize this and thought they created a totally new `js/main.js` that was not related to the original `javascript/main.js`?

*If* the problem is that Git has mis-detected the two renames, you can try tweaking the `-X find-renames=<value>` setting (named `-X rename-threshold=<value>` in older versions of Git).  Making the number lower makes Git more willing to treat apparently-different files as "the same" file.  Making the number higher makes Git less willing to treat such files as "the same", to the point where if you set it to 100%, the files' contents must match exactly.

If all this is the case and this process goes well, you may get what you want and not need any further tricky bits.  If not, well:

#### Doing it by hand

If Git is correct, and your `js/main.js` really *is* renamed while their `js/main.js` really *is* new, it may be inadvisable to combine the files.  However, you *can* do this, using `git merge-file`, which works with ordinary files in the work-tree.  First, you will need to get all three files into your work-tree:

- The merge base version, originally named `javascript/main.js` in the merge base commit (whatever its hash ID is).
- The `--ours` or `HEAD` version, named `js/main.js` in the current commit.
- The `--theirs` version, also named `js/main.js` but in their commit.

Two of these three versions are already available in your work-tree, using the two names Git has announced.

There should also be a copy of each file in your index: the merge base is there as a stage-1 entry, the `--ours` or `HEAD` version is there as a stage-2 entry, and the `--theirs` version is there as a stage-3 entry.  This means that you can use `git show` or `git checkout-index` to get to each.  (In fact, you can probably use `git checkout-idnex --stage=all` to get all of them as temporary files all at once, but I have not experimented with this.)  Since the one you still need is the base version, you could use:

```
git show :1:js/main.js > main.js.base
```

for instance (assuming a Unix-style shell).

Once you have all three files in your work-tree, you can run:

```
git merge-file <head-version> <base-version> <their-version>
```

to produce, in `<head-version>`, a conflict-marker-ized version of the file.  Assuming the names you've shown so far, and writing the stage-1 file to `js/main.js.base`, that would be:

```
git merge-file js/main.js js/main.js.base js/main.js.~<hash>
```