# Merge conflict following submodule move

Tags: git

After moving a submodule in a development branch, I get a merge conflict every time I merge changes up from the master branch.  To resolve, I must `git add mysubmodule`.  How can I avoid resolving this conflict every time I merge up?

Here is a script which illustrates the problem:

```
cd ~/src
git init MyProduct
git init MySubmodule
cd MySubmodule
echo "foo" > foo.txt
git add foo.txt
git commit -m "Add foo.txt"
cd ../MyProduct
echo "bar" > bar.txt
git add bar.txt
git commit -m "Add bar.txt"
git submodule add ../MySubmodule
git commit -m "Add MySubmodule"
git branch development
git checkout development
git mv MySubmodule OurSubmodule
git commit -m "Move MySubmodule to OurSubmodule."
git checkout master
echo "barbar" > bar.txt
git commit -am"Update bar.txt"
git checkout development
git merge master
git add OurSubmodule
git commit -am"Resolve conflict"
```

The merge conflict message I receive on merge is:

```
Auto-merging OurSubmodule
Adding as OurSubmodule~HEAD instead
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for providing such a complete example. I ran it and found `Auto-merging OurSubmodule\nAdding as OurSubmodule~HEAD instead`. I believe this indicates the merge failed to notice the rename. I'm not sure why. This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649882/git-merge-adds-new-file-instead-of-conflict-markers-conflict-rename-add

Comment: Thanks!  The `rm -rf *Submodule` and `git submodule update --init` lines are superfluous; I will remove them from the example. Also I will add the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of figuring out why renames of submodules are not properly detected by `git merge`, I worked around the issue by writing a script to delete and re-add the submodule separately in the maintenance and development branches:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex

# -e: Exit on error
# -x: Print commands as they are executed

# move_submodule: Move a submodule in a development branch while keeping
# it in the same location in a maintenance branch.  If git mv is used to
# move the submodule instead, there will be a merge conflict every time
# changes are merged up to the development branch from the maintenance
# branch.  This script works by deleting the submodule and then readding
# it separately in both branches.  If git mv has already been attempted,
# the moved submodule is also deleted.

if [ $# -ne 5 ]; then
    echo $0: usage: $0 maintenance_branch development_branch submodule_url old_path new_path
    exit 1
fi

maintenance=$1
development=$2
submodule_url=$3
old_path=$4
new_path=$5

repository=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
cd $repository

# Get branches ready
git checkout $maintenance
git pull
git checkout $development
git pull
git submodule update --init --recursive
git merge $maintenance --no-edit
git push

# Delete submodule in $development if you already moved it with git mv.
if [ -d "$new_path" ]; then
    git rm $new_path
    git commit -m"Remove $new_path temporarily to resolve conflict with $maintenance."
    git push
fi

# Delete submodule in $maintenance and merge up.
git checkout $maintenance
git submodule update --init --recursive
git rm $old_path
git commit -m"Remove $old_path temporarily to resolve conflict with $development."
git push
git checkout $development
git submodule update --init --recursive
git merge $maintenance --no-edit
git push

# Re-add submodule in new location in $development.
git submodule add --force $submodule_url $new_path
git commit -m"Re-add $new_path"
git push

# Re-add submodule in original location in $maintenance.
git checkout $maintenance
rm -rf $new_path
git submodule update --init --recursive
git submodule add --force $submodule_url $old_path
git commit -m"Re-add $old_path."
git push

# Merge up, discarding maintenance submodule change.
git checkout $development
rm -rf $old_path
git submodule update --init --recursive
git merge $maintenance --no-edit -s ours
git push
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to running `git submodule update` just before the merge, but I'm not sure why. If `OurSubmodule` is empty the merge goes fine. But if `OurSubmodule` contains a git repo the merge fails.

```
$ git submodule update
Submodule path 'OurSubmodule': checked out 'fc7d6244ff60b52884da1e562edbc9059f758494'

$ git status
On branch development
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git merge master
Auto-merging OurSubmodule
Adding as OurSubmodule~HEAD instead
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

$ git status
On branch development
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Changes to be committed:

    modified:   bar.txt

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    added by us:     OurSubmodule
```

`Adding as OurSubmodule~HEAD instead` indicates that `git merge` failed to notice the rename. Renames in Git are not recorded, Git looks at how similar the contents are. I'm going to guess this is some bug or failing in `git merge`'s rename detection with submodules.

If you `git add OurSubmodule` everything is fine.

```
$ git add OurSubmodule/
$ git status
On branch development
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:

    modified:   bar.txt
```

If you then merge development into master, everything is fine.

Since renaming a submodule is pretty rare, unless you want to dig into the guts of Git I'd suggest fixing the conflict and move on. Git's auto-merge is very good, but conflicts sometimes happen.

---

A note about submodules. Submodules are often more trouble than they're worth. If your code depends on other repositories consider using a package manager instead. Preferably one that can pull straight from Git repositories.

Even when used correctly, the ease with which you can change your code and the submodules to match encourages tightly binding what is supposed to be separated projects together. Keeping them separated into packages which must be worked on and built separately, even if it only takes a minute, encourages good boundaries between the projects.

Comment: Git would need another special case for handling this rename, I think. It's interesting because `git mv` does notice that the path in `.gitmodules` needs updating, and updates it.